# How can I remotely monitor a Node process making sure it's running using outbound HTTP heartbeats vs inbound?

Tags: debian, node.js

I would like the process itself to send heartbeats vs receiving them from services like Amazon Route 53 health checks.

I would like to avoid running a web server on that process.

Comment: Don't do this. Having your process make outbound connections will tell you that it's running, but not whether it is accepting connections, which is what you really want to know.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @MichaelHampton. The process doesn't accept inbound connections as it's a computational server.

Comment: Hmm. In that case... Does it not already connect to somewhere else to accept new work? You could just monitor it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up trying out [Cronitor](https://cronitor.io/) and so far it does the job. Pricing is a bit aggressive though. They do offer a free plan for one monitor but a hobbyist plan would have nailed their offering.

Here is the code I use to send heartbeats.

`logger.captureException` is a custom error reporting wrapper for [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/).

```
const sendHeartbeat = function() {
    request.get('https://cronitor.link/******/complete?auth_key=' + process.env.CRONITOR_AUTH_KEY, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            logger.captureException(error);
        }
        setTimeout(sendHeartbeat, 60 * 1000); // Run once per minute
    });
};
sendHeartbeat();
```

Comment: https://healthchecks.io would also work for this, and has a Hobbyist plan with 20 fee checks included. </plug>